# Show that $\sqrt{ab}$ is the limitpoint of the nested interval

Tags: real-analysis

I already know that positve $a,b$ we have

$\frac{a+b}{2}\geq\sqrt{ab}\geq\frac{2ab}{a+b}$

Given, $0<a<b$ and $I_n=[a_n,b_n]$ with $I_1=[a,b]$ and $I_{n+1}=[\frac{2a_nb_n}{a_n+b_n},\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}]$. I should show that $I_n$ is a nested interval and that the unique Point it converges to is $\sqrt{ab}$.

I have got Problems to show that the Point that it converges to is $\sqrt{ab}$

---

To show that it is a nested interval I work with induction

I show

$a<\frac{2ab}{a+b}\iff a(a+b)-2ab<0\iff a^2-ab<0\iff a(a-b)<0$. Since $b>a$ this is true.

Also

$b>\frac{a+b}{2}\iff b>a$ which is also true by assumption

The inequality in the middle follows from the Formula above

Inductionstep

I can assume $a_{n}<b_{n}$ The proof for the inductionstep works the same way which means it was not necessary to prove it by induction.

We have proved $I_{n+1}\subset I_n$

Now assume $\epsilon>0$

We have a look at $|I_{n+1}|$

Then $b_{n+1}-a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}-\frac{2a_nb_n}{a_n+b_n}=\frac{(a_n+b_n)^2-4a_nb_n}{2(a_n+b_n)}=\frac{a_n^2+2a_nb_n+b_n^2}{2(a_n+b_n)}=\frac{(a_n-b_n)^2}{2(a_n+b_n)}=\frac{(b_n-a_n)^2}{2(a_n+b_n)}=(b_n-a_n)\frac{b_n-a_n}{2(a_n+b_n)}<(b_n-a_n)\frac 1 2$

$\Longrightarrow$

$|I_{n+1}|=b_{n+1}-a_{n+1}<(\frac{1}{2})^n(b-a)<\epsilon$ We know that such an $n$ exists by archimedian property

So $I_n$ is a nested interval

---

---

Now I have to prove that $\sqrt{ab}$ is within every interval.

It is true for $I_1$

because

$a<\sqrt{ab}\iff a<b$ and $b>\sqrt{ab}\iff b>a$

The inductionstep is too hard

I have to show

$\sqrt{ab}>\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}$

and

$\sqrt{ab}<\frac{2a_nb_n}{a_n+b_n}$

How can I start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 
$$
a_{n+1}b_{n+1} = \frac{2a_nb_n}{a_n+b_n} \cdot\frac{a_n+b_n}{2} = a_nb_n \, ,
$$and consequently $a_n b_n = ab$ for all $n$. The inequality between the harmonic/geometric/arithmetic means then shows that
$$
 b_{n+1} = \operatorname{HM}(a_n, b_n) \le \sqrt{ab} \le \operatorname {AM}(a_n, b_n) = a_{n+1} 
$$
for all $n$, i.e. $\sqrt{ab} \in I_{n+1}$.

You already showed that the $I_n$ are a sequence of nested intervals with lengths converging to zero, therefore $\sqrt{ab}$ is the unique point contained in all intervals.

Comment: Can you tell me how you 'saw' this?

Comment: @RM777: I “saw” that $b_{n+1} = \operatorname{HM}(a_n, b_n)$ and $a_{n+1} = \operatorname{AM}(a_n, b_n)$, that suggests to try HM<=GM<=AM.

Comment: I see I really must get into the habit to make use of all information